# Memcache doesn't work in xampp. Class 'Memcache' not found

Tags: php, apache, memcached, xampp

I did absolutely everything what is written in here: http://www.leonardaustin.com/technical/how-to-install-memcached-on-xampp-on-windows-7

I see now in task manager that memcache server is running, I refreshed apache and so on, but I still get an error `Class 'Memcache' not found`.

What should I do? Maybe there is an error in the tutorial?

I am on the Vista 32

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just downloaded the newest version of XAMPP and it works. So, don't forget to update to the newest version of XAMPP.

Answer (score 3):

The error indicates that memcache extension is not loaded. Make sure to `"extension=php_memcache.dll"` in php.ini points to the **actual location** of the file, and to restart your httpd server afterwards.

Comment: it is really the actual location.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem for 3 hours.  I finally installed the DLL for VC6 not 9 and that worked great.  For Windows 7, 32bit.  file: php_memcache-cvs-20090703-5.3-VC6-x86

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your PHP in x86 or x64, (NOT Your Windows)
[image: On this screen, php_info() tells Windows is 64bit, but PHP is on x86, so you should choose x86 dll]

On this screen, php_info() tells Windows is 64bit, but PHP is on x86, so you should choose x86 dll
Choose correctly package to download and install should solve your problems